Identify this movie that starts with a tale from jewish folklore
This hollywood movie is recent (i saw it around 2008)
The entire plot of the movie has nothing to do with the first scene, which is a re-telling of old Jewish folklore tale.
The scene starts with a husband enters his home and tells his wife that he invited another man to dinner.
His wife freaks out and tells him that he has invited a "debuk" or something like that, meaning that he had met a ghost. She tells him that this ghost takes the image of people who had died. 
They discuss what to do, then the invited man arrives. They let him in and serve him a plate. Then they stab him. He is shocked and in pain. Tries to leave. I think it is revealed that he was not a ghost and the wife was mistaken.
The scene ends, and the movie starts with no reference to this scene at all as I said.

The Coen Brothers' A Serious Man from 2009 begins with this old Jewish anecdote.

In a prologue, a Jewish man in an unnamed Eastern European shtetl tells his wife that he was helped on his way home by Reb Groshkover, whom he has invited in for soup. She says Groshkover is dead and must be a dybbuk. Groshkover (Fyvush Finkel) arrives and laughs off the accusation, but she plunges an icepick into his chest. Bleeding, he exits into the snowy night.

Here's the scene:



